# Python: Continuously and cancelably repeat execution with fixed interval

Tags: python, multithreading, vim, multiprocessing

What is the best way to continuously repeat the execution of a given function at a fixed interval while being able to terminate the executor (thread or process) immediately?

Basically I know two approaches:

1. use multiprocessing and function with infinite cycle and `time.sleep` at the end. Processing is terminated with `process.terminate()` in any state.
2. use threading and constantly recreate timers at the end of the thread function. Processing is terminated by `timer.cancel()` while sleeping.

(both “in any state” and “while sleeping” are fine, even though the latter may be not immediate). The problem is that I have to use both multiprocessing and threading as the latter appears not to work on ARM (some fuzzy interaction of python interpreter and vim, outside of vim everything is fine) (I was using the second approach there, have not tried threading+cycle; no code is currently left) and the former spawns way too many processes which I would like not to see unless really required. This leads to a problem of having to code two different approaches while `threading` with cycle is just a few more imports for drop-in replacements of all `multiprocessing` stuff wrapped in `if`/`else` (except that there is no `thread.terminate()`). Is there some better way to do the job?

Currently used code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/aurum/src/1dc9ed228ca82ad6bf5b718df07148064420a9d7/python/aurum/repeatedcmd.py) (currently with cycle for both jobs), but I do not think it will be much useful to answer the question.

**Update**: The reason why I am using this solution are functions that display file status (and some other things like branch) in version control systems in vim statusline. These statuses must be updated, but updating them immediately cannot be done without using hooks and I have no idea how to set hooks temporary and remove on vim quit without possibly spoiling user configuration. Thus standard solution is cache expiring after N seconds. But when cache expired I need to do an expensive shell call and the delay appears to be noticeable, the more noticeable the heavier IO load is. What I am implementing now is updating values for viewed buffers each N seconds in a separate process thus delays are bothering that process and not me. Threads are likely to also work because GIL does not affect calls to external programs.

Comment: This is Google's top result if you search for "cancelably".

Comment: @Junnux And what result? Because I know how to do task with both processing and threading, I do not know how not to have too much code. I do not see anything which shows me a way to do this in a uniform way. One answer is timer, second one clearly states “if thread is in system call (time.sleep(), socket.accept(), ...), the exception is simply ignored”.

Comment: @Junuxx I guess I know what you meant: I used an unexisting word, didn’t I?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry I don't have something more constructive to contribute :P

Comment: @ZyX, "unexisting" is nonexistent as well. (no offence, just FYI)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on why a single long-lived thread that loops infinitely over the tasks wouldn't work for you?  Or why you end up with many processes in the multiprocess option?

My immediate reaction would have been a single thread with a queue to feed it things to do.  But I may be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: I have a number of jobs, each of them must be repeated with a given interval. I can, of course, merge them into one process, but it requires some hard job deducing intervals between jobs, coding jobs deletion and so on + some function which will determine whether I need a new process. Maybe I will do this some time after, but for now it seems too hard for nothing. There should be really ~four (2+{number_of_windows}) threads running at once, current implementation makes more: 2+{number_of_files} with unneeded processes sleeping as I was afraid of the cost of spawning new process.

Comment: I will limit processes to ~four after some profiling (I have an opinion that I was overoptimizing when I introduced pausing instead of just killing processes), but it does not make me happy looking at five identical vim PIDs.

Comment: Long-living thread with one task like now it does one process is not working for me because I will have to wait until `time.sleep()` finishes before thread is deleted. Most of time it is OK, but not when vim is exiting. And nothing may prevent user from setting update interval to 1 minute or more in case he is sure he won’t edit files outside of current vim instance and will use only aurum commands instead of plain VCS commands in shell.

Comment: Updated question with the description of the actual task.

Comment: You could have the thread continually polling a queue of instructions, and look for a "shutdown" command.  That could happen every few seconds, irrespective of the time between tasks (ie. while it's "sleeping", it's still watching the queue for the shutdown).  You could send that shutdown command from the vim signal handler.

Comment: I understand. And it will work for processes as well. More, for me it will work well on my desktop. But I am unsure whether it is going to work well for other users. // Vim does not raise signals to shutdown itself, neither it allows to override handlers in VimL (python can do this though, but I don’t know how to call an original handler), but it uses events so it is doable and it was done for the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how do it simply and/or cleanly in Python, but I was wondering if maybe you couldn't take avantage of an existing system scheduler, e.g. crontab for *nix system.

There is an [API in python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=python-crontab&%3aaction=display)  and it might satisfied your needs.

Comment: a) It does not work not on linux b) it alters global state, and thus is very painful to cleanup in case vim crashes c) it is not very good idea to make cron run jobs with a few seconds intervals d) all IPC I can imagine in this case also uses some too global state: filesystem or free port. What I actually want is make me not suffer from delays caused by `git status` calls in aurum plugin (used to display current file status in statusline) (delays when using mercurial driver are unnoticeable).

Comment: Solution in case python is unavailable is using cache, but it still does not make shell calls unnoticeable.